# duplicate selection in text() XPath selector

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I'm trying to select all nodes with text that contain a certain word (ex: Company) because the word needs to have a register mark.

Here is part of the XHTML (this `<p>` is inside a table cell).

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <a style="color:#0E5A8B; text-decoration:none" target="_blank" href="http://www.trekk.com">
      <span class="title">
        A Company Content Title
      </span>
    </a>
    <br />
    <span style="color:#000000">
      February 23, 2010 10:00 A.M. PT<br />
    </span>
  </strong>
  Sample Content<br />
  <a style="color:#000" target="_blank" href="http://www.trekk.com">
    Register now
  </a>
</p>
```

I load the XHTML into a `System.Xml.XmlDocument` and try to select the nodes using

```
NewsletterHtmlDoc.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(),'Company')]")
```

The resulting XmlNodeList contains 2 XmlNodes.

1. `<p>` with InnerText = `A Company Content Title February 23, 2010 10:00 A.M. PT Sample Content Register now`
2. `<span class="title">` with InnerText = `A Company Content Title`

My goal is to just select the 2nd one, the `<span>` tag and am not sure why `<p>` tag is also being selected.  If it selects `<p>`, but why wouldn't it also select the `<strong>` or `<a>`, and why not the `<table>` or `<td>` that contain the `<p>`?

Comment: What's different about #2 such that you want it but not #1?

Comment: Are you sure this is the result you're getting? I just tried that XPath expression against that source document and all I got was the `span` element. That's what I expect that expression to return. Are you sure either that `p` doesn't contain more than you think it does or perhaps are you accidentally adding the root node to your node set before or after you run the `SelectNodes` function?

Comment: #1 won't work because I need to inject a registered mark after the word.  If I modify and set the InnerText of <p> I don't think it would update the node as expected.

I need to find the first occurence of the word to add the register mark.  It gets skipped if it's in a title, unless it only occurs in the title.

Could be minor differences in XPath engines which would cause different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The *Sample Content* text was part of the InnerText of the `<p>` element and caused the entire InnerText of the `<p>` element to be found. Putting *Sample Content* in its own element removed any immediate InnerText from the `<p>` element and fixed the problem.

```
<p>
  <strong>
    <a style="color:#0E5A8B; text-decoration:none" target="_blank" href="http://www.trekk.com">
      <span class="title">
        A Company Content Title
      </span>
    </a>
    <br />
    <span style="color:#000000">
      February 23, 2010 10:00 A.M. PT<br />
    </span>
  </strong>
  <span>
    Sample Content
  </span>
  <br />
  <a style="color:#000" target="_blank" href="http://www.trekk.com">
    Register now
  </a>
</p>
```